# Calculating the intersection volume of 2 3D volumes defined by point and accuracy

Tags: geometry, 3d, volume, solid-geometry

I'm surprised this hasn't been asked before - it may be that my ability to search the site is hampered by being on the app!

I have $2$ 3D points $(X_1, Y_1, Z_1)$ and $(X_2,Y_2,Z_2)$ each with associated accuracy in those dimensions $(dX_1,dY_1,dZ_1)$ and $(dX_2,dY_2,dZ_2)$. I'm treating these accuracies as a volume in which the points exist. I'd like to try and calculate:

1. If the volumes intersect,
2. The volume of the intersection if they do intersect.

I know how to calculate is two lines intersect but I have no idea how to transfer that over to 3D volumes!

Comment: No easy way... test if at least one of the eight points around one of your coordinates lies in all the three intervals around the other set of coordinates. The intersection volume depends on how many points lie in the other volume.

Comment: Given that these accuracy volumes are rectangular prisms, isn't a common feature of any overlap that the sum of all three pairs of deltas (dX1 + dX2 etc) be greater the X2 - X1 etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The condition for X: $\left | X_{1}-X_{2} \right |< dX_{1}+dX_{2}$. Now extend it to y and z. All of them need to be fulfilled simultaneously to get a intersection.
2. The intersection is rectangular prism on its own. You need to measure the overlap for each dimension separately.  This is accomplished by first by comparing the values of $X_{1}$ to $X_{2}$ and properly use $dX_{i}$ to calculate the overlap for X dimension. Than do the same for Y and Z. I assume you know how to do the overlap computation.